# Flutter - ChangeNotifierProxyProvider package

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been using the Provider package  3.1.0 version last year to share value  between providers ,like that :

```
...
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: Auth(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
      builder: (ctx, auth, previousProd) => Prod(
            auth.cred,
            previousProd,
          ),
    ),
    ),
  ],)
...
```

Now with the version 4.1.3 two parameters are required : `create` and `update`

And i got stuck editing my application , I tried that :

```
...
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: Auth(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
      update: (ctx, auth, previousProd) => Prod(
            auth.cred,
            previousProd,
          ),
    ),
    ),
  ],)
...
```

It shows that `the create parameter is required` as i said 
But i cannot figure out how to use that parameter ,

Can someone please help me ,i would appreciate that ,
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProxyProvider doesn't require the create parameter but ChangeNotifierProxyProvider does, to avoid creating a ChangeNotifier each time (with ProxyProvider there is no problem because is a simple class with no listeners). The create is called once, while the update can be called multiple times, so the code for a ChangeNotifierProxyProvider should look like this

```
 ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
   create: (_) => Prod(),
   update: (_, auth, product) => product..credential = auth.cred,
   //instead of creating a new object Prod(), just reuse the existing one and set the new values
   child: ...
 )
```

And the Prod class

```
class Prod extends ChangeNotifier{
  Credential _cred;

  Prod(){
    //if you want to initialize some values
  }

  set credential(Credential credential) => _cred = credential;
  //or some other logic you do here with the auth.cred
}
```

Now each time Auth change and notifies the ProxyProvider it will reuse the same object created in create and just change the parameter credential (_cread)